# Process tracking with long polling, txt file as buffer

Tags: php, jquery, json, long-polling

I'm using long polling to get the status of a process by using a txt file as a buffer. I'm starting a process via AJAX and waiting the response from that call, I also start checking that process by another AJAX call.

The timeline looks like this:

```
Calls        |  Process Length (time)
=============|============================================================
Main AJAX    | |--------------------------------------------------------|
Sub check #1 | |-------|
Sub check #2 |         |--------|
Sub check #3 |                  |---------|
.....        | 
Sub check #n |                                                   |------|
```

The code I'm providing is for the sub checks.

Like this:

**Server-side**

```
<?php 
   append_to_txt_json("status", "started operation");
   do_operation_1();
   append_to_txt_json("status", "op#1 finished");
   do_operation_2();
   append_to_txt_json("status", "op#2 finished");
   do_operation_last();
   append_to_txt_json("status", "success");

   function do_operation_1(){
       do_unimportant_1();
       append_to_txt_json("sub1_result", do_sub(1));
       do_unimportant_2();
   }

   function append_to_txt_json($key, $str){
       $file_path = "ajax_result.txt";
       $data = file_get_contents($file_path);
       if(!empty($data)){
            $contents = json_decode($data);
            if(empty($contents)){
                $contents = (object)[];
            }
       }else{
            $contents = (object)[];
       }
       if(property_exists($contents, $key)){
           if(!is_array($contents->{$key})){
               $temp = $contents->{$key};
               $contents->{$key} = [$temp, $str];
           }else{
               $contents->{$key}[] = $str;
           }
       }else{
           $contents->{$key} = $str;
       }
       file_put_contents($file_path, json_encode($contents), LOCK_SH);
   }
?>
```

**Client-side**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var finishPolling = false;
    var poll = function() {
        if (finishPolling === true) {
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_result.txt?tz=" + (+new Date()),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                // do some parsing, formatting etc
                if ((data.status instanceof Array && data.status[data.status.length - 1] === 'success') || (data.status == 'success')) {
                    finishPolling = true;
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                //finishPolling = true;
            },
            complete: function() {
                if(finishPolling === false){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        poll();
                    }, 2000);
                }
            },
            timeout: 4000
        });
    };
</script>
```

But sometimes, the client tries to access the - not yet fully written file - and gets a half and invalid JSON response from that file. And that causes an error on the client ajax call, executing the `.error()` method.

How do I overcome this situation?

Is there any other method to do this?